# load data from s3 to mySQL running EC2 instance (not RDS)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to able able to use the load data infile command in mySQL, but instead of loading the data from a local file I want to load it from a CSV file.

I.e., if the file is in local storage it'd look like:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE'C:\\abc.csv' INTO TABLE abc
```

But if it's in S3, not sure how I could do something like this.

Is this possible?

NOTE: this is not an RDS machine, so this command does not seem to work:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-template-copys3tords.html

Comment: Can you copy the S3 file to a local location - i.e. with the [aws cli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) run something like `s3 cp s3://bucket/file.csv c:\\somewhere\file.csv`?

Comment: @stdunbar Thanks.  yes I can, but shouldn't there be a way to avoid unnecessary data copy and data transfers? That's the goal of this Q.  I am transfering TBs of data so copy brings additional cost and time.

Comment: Ultimately you're looking to stream data into the database from S3 and, without some code, you're not going to be able to do that directly. The issue is that the MySQL command line won't stream from S3.  You're other option is to mount S3 as a file system (something like [s3fs-fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse)).  This makes S3 appear to be a file system.

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql` CLI allows you to execute STDIN as a stream of SQL statements.

Using a combination of the `s3` CLI and `mkfifo`, you can stream data out of s3.

Then it's a simple matter of connecting the streams with something that re-formats the CSV into valid SQL.

```
mkfifo /tmp/mypipe
s3 cp s3://your/s3/object /tmp/mypipe
python transform_csv_to_sql.py < /tmp/mypipe | mysql target_database
```

You might be able to remove the python step and use MySQL's CSV code if you tell MySQL to load the data directly from your fifo:

```
mkfifo /tmp/mypipe
s3 cp s3://your/s3/object /tmp/mypipe
mysql target_database --execute "LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/mypipe'"
```

Good luck!